# Converting multiple rows to multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data something like this:

```
Team    Month   Count_of_Stores
  a      4       10
  b      4        4
  c      4        6
  a      5        8
  b      5       14
  e      5        9
  a      6        7
  b      6        3
  f      6        1
```

I working to get an output something like this converting the rows to columns:

Team    Month   Count_of_Stores Team    Month   Count_of_Stores Team    Month   Count_of_Stores
a   4   10  a   5   8   a   6   7
b   4   4   b   5   14  b   6   3
c   4   6   e   5   9   f   6   1

I am sure pivot should be of great help here, but confused in the appropriate usage here. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use conditional aggregation here but how do you know the order of the results? You have no way in the data posted to order the results.

Comment: @SeanLange I actually do group it based on another criteria which is teams which i haven't mentioned here. So in that way the data is being ordered and grouped.

Comment: OK but with the data you provided it is impossible to be consistent with ordering. Perhaps you can share some more details? [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks sean! Thats right. I think my data is incomplete and the code suggested by  "IsItGreyOrGray"  looks almost close below. What do you think?

Comment: The code provided in that answer is about all you can get with no way to ensure ordering. In other words you will get values for months 4,5 and 6 but have no way to know which value of each will appear next to each other. Meaning one time you may get 4,10-5,8-6,7 and another get 4,6-5,14-6,7 on the same row.

Comment: How about if I GROUP BY and ORDER BY the team names. Still wouldn't work? I ran it more than ten times now and compared the results everytime. I see there is consistency in the results all the ten times i ran for the exact same team name and for all the team names for the three months i am getting the same result.

Comment: There are no team names in the sample you provided so how could I answer that? To fully understand the challenges of ordering data when not using an order by see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx).

Comment: I think it is time you share the **entire** problem, not just the minimal amount. This really isn't that difficult but you are now 18 hours into this question with no solid answer. Providing the whole question up front makes this easier on everybody.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I am still learning here. Apologies. My exact question is. I have 100's of teams with three different months (ex:4,5,6) with different store counts for the teams. now i would like to bring the data as grouped according to the teams based on each month on different columns based on the month. The teams in the 4th month need not be necessarily be available in 5th month and vice versa

Comment: Team Month Count_of_Stores
a 4 10
b 4 4
c 4 6
a 5 8
b 5 14
e 5 9
a 6 7
b 6 3
f 6 1

Comment: And i would like to get theo/p like this
Team Month Count_of_Stores Team Month Count_of_Stores Team Month Count_of_Stores
a 4 10 a 5 8 a 6 7
b 4 4 b 5 14 b 6 3
c 4 6 e 5 9 f 6 1

Comment: again sincere apologies for incomplete data.

Comment: Comments are horrible for code or data. You should instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52375708/edit) your question and include the relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring team association based on the data provided. Something like the below could work for you (demo: http://rextester.com/GQHPV34978)

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
    [teamID] INT,
    [month] INT,
    [count_of_stores] INT
)

INSERT INTO temp
VALUES 
(1,4,10),
(2,4,4),
(3,4,6),
(1,5,8),
(2,5,14),
(3,5,9),
(1,6,7),
(2,6,3),
(3,6,1)

SELECT [teamID], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 4 THEN MONTH END )AS Month,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 4 THEN count_of_stores END )  AS Count_of_Stores,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 5 THEN MONTH END )AS Month,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 5 THEN count_of_stores END )  AS Count_of_Stores ,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 6 THEN MONTH END )AS Month,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 6 THEN count_of_stores END )  AS Count_of_Stores 
FROM temp
GROUP BY teamID
```

Updating with the following based on new information (demo:http://rextester.com/JIZQX61960)

```
create TABLE #temp
(
    [teamID] varchar,
    [month] INT,
    [count_of_stores] INT
)

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES 
('a',4,10),
('b',4,4),
('c',4,6),
('a',5,8),
('b',5,14),
('e',5,9),
('a',6,7),
('b',6,3),
('f',6,1);


WITH monthGrouping AS
(
    SELECT row_number() over (partition by month order by month) as rn, [teamID], [month],[count_of_stores] FROM #temp
)

SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 4 THEN [teamID] END )AS [teamID],
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 4 THEN MONTH END )AS Month,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 4 THEN count_of_stores END )  AS Count_of_Stores,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 5 THEN [teamID] END )AS [teamID],
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 5 THEN MONTH END )AS Month,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 5 THEN count_of_stores END )  AS Count_of_Stores ,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 6 THEN [teamID] END )AS [teamID],
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 6 THEN MONTH END )AS Month,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 6 THEN count_of_stores END )  AS Count_of_Stores 
FROM monthGrouping
GROUP BY rn
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks good. this works for me. But What if i have different teams names or Id's. Say i have nine different team names or ID's for all the nine entries. In that case, is it possible to still split them and arrange?  When i implement this logic,  think i will be left with lot of NULLS values if i am not wrong. IS that right? what do you think?

Comment: Yes, you can be left with nulls if you are using different names or IDs. If you have different teams spanning across the months you could row_number() them by month and use the same type of data rotation by grouping off of that... similar to [link](http://rextester.com/SNYDD79242). In order to give the best implementation advice, we really need to see an example of what the final results would be expected to look like.

Comment: Team Month Count_of_Stores a 4 10 b 4 4 c 4 6 a 5 8 b 5 14 e 5 9 a 6 7 b 6 3 f 6 1

Comment: And i would like to get theo/p like this Team Month Count_of_Stores Team Month Count_of_Stores Team Month Count_of_Stores a 4 10 a 5 8 a 6 7 b 4 4 b 5 14 b 6 3 c 4 6 e 5 9 f 6 1

Comment: That's awesome! Worked like magic. Thanks a lot. And apologies for the confusion and incomplete data in the beginning.